# Chrome Audit - Text is invisible while webfonts are loading

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have used `font-display: auto` on `@font-face`. But Chrome is complaining:

> 1 Text is invisible while webfonts are loading
>
> Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading. Learn more.

## CSS code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "basis-grotesque-pro";
  font-display: auto;
  src: url('/url/medium-pro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

In chromse sources tab, all other CSS properties are marked `red`, but font-display is `black`. What could be the reason? How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried closing your `src` attribute with a `;` ?
( I realise my answer seems condescending, but sometimes it's the simple things)

Comment: @AaronMcGuire Yes!